# Making A Search Query And Getting Results

Tags: web-services, client-server

I am planning on making a certain software but I want to make sure to use the right development tools.

The project will use a website that has data (Let's say a music library).

On one hand:
The program will search the site for specific data (Artist X, Title Y).
The program retrieves a list of search results among which the user picks one to download.

On the other hand:
The program will allow a user to upload a file to the server, this file will have tags (Artist, Title) including his username.

Similar to the Minilyrics add-on to windows media player.

My question is what are the right tools to make this kind of project (Client based/Server based).

I am planning on using Visual Basic but I am not sure if its the right decision...

Thanks

Comment: You can use SOAP or REST webservice.

Comment: The question is too imprecise. Too many answers would apply. You *can* use essentially any language or architecture (as long as it works under your platform and can speak HTTP) to get it working. You should choose the one that is easiest for you to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite big question with lots of small ones inside.

First, the way to communicate between server and client is mostly based on RESTful webservices. But, it really depends on your use cases and needs.

The same applies to your question regarding the "right tools". What skills do you have? Which dependencies do you have? What is your target audience?

So, it is quite hard to give you  "the one and only" answer...